# Error using \usepackage{listings}

Tags: listings, supertabular, e-tex

If I include the package `listings` I can't compile my document anymore. There is an error saying:

```
!No room for new \dimen.\ck ... \else \ermesage{No room...}
File: \latex\sueprtabluar\supertabular.sty
```

Is this enough information for anyone to help get it running,
or maybe there is an other solution printing source code style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write after the documentclass:

```
\usepackage{etex}
```

it enables the capabilities of the etex engine, e.g. more registers for dimensions etc

Comment: thx.. it works. just two, sentences why it fix it?

Comment: done, see edit ...

Answer (score 3):

You seem to load to many packages which require to many dimension registers.
Looks like the package which requests the one-to-many is the `supertabular` package. This has nothing special to do with `listings`. The reason the error appeared when you started to use it was just that it increased the number of required dimension registers over the available limit.

This is also explained in more detail [in the TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-noroom).

Try to reduce the number of packages you are using.
Also check that you are using [eTeX](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-etex) which increases the number of registers a lot.

Comment: _all_ engines use etex by default.

Comment: @Herbert: I thought so. But I didn't knew that the number of registers is not extended by default, therefore I assumed that on his installation etex is somehow disabled.